# If i revoked my Developer and distribution it'll affect to my Live app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to know that if I revoked my Developer and Distribution certificate and obtain new one it'll affect to my Existing App.

Answer (score 1):

No. It will not affect it/them. You use this certificates to just to sign the apps when submitting to review.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this happen when I have revoked my certificates for debug and dist.  From my experience, Apple checks your certificates when you submit the app, but not every time it's installed.  If you have anything in AdHoc distribution, that would be affected as every time an AdHoc app is installed it checks that cert.  Users wouldn't be able to install the adhoc with the now invalid adhoc cert.  Recompiling ad-hoc builds with a new cert should solve that problem.

Comment: recompiling and then giving out the new .ipa file solves the problem